# Graph - Algorithm to position nodes

Tags: graph, tree

I am trying to create a dynamic graph where users can add new nodes using [ELK.js](https://www.eclipse.org/elk/)

The graph is a tree that has one root node. I am trying to set the position of nodes in a row using **(x,y)** position *(y is not important for now).*

**Assumptions:**

- Lower x value brings the node to the left.
- Two nodes in one row can't have the same x value.
- When we add a new node it should appear on the right of other children if available (the green box in row 2 and 3 for example are a new nodes)
- New nodes can be added to every row at any moment (green box in row 2 and row 3)
- Max number we can use to set **x** value is 16 digit long: **9999999999999999**

[image: Graph example]

A simple example of how positions behave can be found [here](https://rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/elklive/json.html?compressedContent=N4KABGBECWAmkC5ICcD2qAukA04oBsBDAT1QFcMB5ABw2lQDsBnRUCCSAU3wGsA6QvgDmqZNAwALALaJIRYp2Sd4udlG79Y0JQGM6jWQCUAkgHEAEgBUceDhr7VCyOvobQGQgXugA3Qhk5EDGQyTlV2Ll4+CWhFJx0JYnNCBlh8dyFZYwA5AGEAGQBVABEAUQB9XPNjfOLDUuybNUj+dwDkQm8fTnySciwEYNC8AF9wyATofFglBkQAbVswNjUoOFkhNDJqAEYm1blCACNuFgRF1fYVy44AgA8ByE3yXcgltRH3sABdcOb5fo0Vxna4HeyCERiSQyJDyRTKfaXFrRWIdZAJJIpNIZWQAZVKAAUAIKGImWCpVGp1BqIsFRLS6VyyYqUADqjT+dP4jmc4nobg8DicLn5iAADJzmvYeSLGBkvHQ-AEgiEwl87FE4UpYHwtfKmMF-JwhMREFBsqVLKzKIYANLlXHGACyBPypQAGrS1AByexa5R8BioWCcAlEHScKScBgYPhHfgAM2gd2URPSQgYUZj3oQYG9ACEifkiXlSsVvZL2L7NSR4TqdGgmEwMk73NApNAAF7+fl8JiR6DGGNxLqcHN5oZjr5jL4TGLTWYLdXLZccdZIBh7SvNADucEkiAAzBLV1AJJxoEIJANj9uIkQTvgzhcbmpQa-bpwHrJN28P+xPn-X5TwBCggX5Jhc3fG5q25VBm1ccdvQlMAxQrU8NW5YU+TlQUZRwuYEBPf9AJuGdX2g5p10gBgACYvQOPdYAPBBb1PSBz0va8j2Ij9DkfZ8MJXf9mnuR46L-ETSNfYD-1AqhaAgqChORfDXHlNTRSIu8fWleCCPHSAdmwVDJNfaTVnIm5KIiaiGEPBjd33CQeJ0s8LyvG9eNffjTiXEThICqAxJ-ByhIsy5ZI-eTwMYSDAv-VTsPUvDkq07yP1ghx9MQ3NvVoky0LciKALvGy13gDcABZHIiJiWLYxLOM81z2IfPzziE8qDhC6qzI-Eq1Ci18YsUuLlICpLeRSzxNIMbShKy6gcv5JDD0K9CSOXKzLm6mBKpoqqarcyB6pc1iMqRZruIuk72qffyRO60Sv3Eo7+vM09vm2sr2LsqqAFZao4M7Wqajybsavj7sEgLnoiXrDqB8Kvu2r5hoiZQhE4WHrL+g7NwAYgkk6mHIdEccexLfy+k6MCcbGMFx6n6NR8zfsSuydmJhzSfJiNmb4mmgLphnOCZqmhbCoCfuXPaueJ472LJsgKcFnzhY-DGkXp5BGfVm5Do+1ZvvZuX8Z-KrFaVxKVbVyWNZq2n2N1-WHcNhh3rZsiOb4-7FaBvnVYF92kU942htFvXxYNsPAYj9hTbI9Glh2hLbIO55tnoytfIezqKJd16Ni2ahWc+yLc9G4FWGXKbZQFWa0vmnZp1zyYF2jUP06RLnA-Y0HbvY66vNlwvOYJ2j+8SweoZ8keeLRyLU7wKKuFgbHBNXkBAKAA) (see the position of nodes n2, n3, n4 and change them in JSON)

I am trying not to calculate every position of every node in a row. I tried a lot of different numbers but I stuck and need fresh ideas.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you have the tree stored in some other, basic data structure as well, or are you directly working with this structure without any graph structure backing it up? What is the programming language? What are the endpoints/functions that are called when the user requests a node to be added somewhere?

Comment: @trincot You are right I meant the length of the number. My mistake. I think 16 digits would be more obvious 9999999999999999. 
For now I don't have any backend ready so I am creating nodes by my own. 
I am using ELK to generate final data structure which is based on JSON which you can find in example which I posted above.
I am using angular for frontend and for now I am storing nodes in NgRx or (RxJs) store. So I am mocking integration with backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this as follows:

When a new node is the first one on its level, give it 0 as its x-value.

When it is not the first, find out what its immediate two siblings are on that level (one at the left, one at the right of the node). In some cases you'll need to traverse from the node via one or more of its ancestor(s) to find such immediate sibling.

Get the x-values of these two siblings, and take the average of those two values for the new node's x value.

It might be that there is only a sibling at one side. If there is no sibling at the right side, take the average between the left siblings's x-value and 10<sup>16</sup>. If it is the left sibling that is missing, take the average between the right siblings's x-value and -10<sup>16</sup>.

This practically means you use an initial range of -10<sup>16</sup>...10<sup>16</sup> and keep cutting segments in half when a new node must be placed within a segment.

Comment: I need some time to implement it but it looks like something I need. Thank you :) I will let you know how it went.